# How to edit Wordpress code for a specific page?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I feel kind of stupid asking this but... I have three pages on my website. There is one of them I want to edit. How do I access the code of this page? I need to change the size of a Google Maps I have embedded on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Go edit this page, in the right sidebar look for Template in page attributes box. This page should be using a template, go to your theme folder and look for a php file with the similar name, when you open, it should have the exact template name in the header, that's where you can edit the code of this page assuming that it use a template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems that my theme doesn't have a "template" in the attributes box. Do you know what to do then?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by playing around with some divs in the css.